# Database(SQLite) transaction for downstream operators with rxJava

Tags: java, sqlite, transactions, rx-java

Assuming i have some stream of items:

```
Observable<Item> stream = ...
```

What am i trying to achieve?

- Stream has any amount of operations. All operations before beginning a transaction should be run outside of the transaction
- Somehow start transaction in the middle of the stream `db.beginTransaction()`
- All operators after starting transaction should be run inside the transaction
- Transaction have to be completed in case of successful operations `db.setTransactionSuccessful`
- Transaction have to be always ended `db.endTransaction`
- It will be great to have both snippets : open **one** transaction for all items in downstream operations; open and close transaction for **each** item in the stream

> 

```
//some upstream operators
stream.doOnNext(i -> ...)
    .map(i -> ...)
    //somehow start transaction here
    //operator inside transaction. All database changes will be reverted in case error
    .doOnNext(i -> /*database ops*/)
    .subscribe()
```

PS: db is application scoped instance of writable `SQLiteDatabase`

I have a solution now. But maybe you have any suggestions about more cleaner way?

Comment: Do you want separate transactions for each of the `Item`s coming from the source? What is `database`? Is it a connection for this particular item, or some global variable? If it is global, then transaction would be global as well. Would you like transaction to last until all items processed then?

Comment: `database` is a global instance (application scoped ) of writeable `SQLiteDatabase`. I wanna open one transaction for processing all items of stream. But new transaction for each item is also interesting approach. You have mentioned that such transaction is global, is it restricts something?

Comment: Global transaction looks weird to me. That means single transaction is going to include all database activities happening in your program at the same time. As a consequence it should not matter much when exactly you start your transaction. Every operation in your pipeline will be repeated for each item. First item shall open transaction, and *all* operations for subsequent items are gonna be inside that transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) For the case when all items are processed in single transaction:

```
stream
    .doOnSubscribe(d -> database.beginTransaction())
    . ...
    .subscribe(v -> {...},
        e -> database.endTransaction(),
        () -> { database.setTransactionSuccessful(); database.endTransaction(); })
```

2) For the case when there is separate transaction for each item:

```
class ItemWithTransaction {
    Item item;
    Connection conn; // connection associated with this item
    boolean rollback;
}

stream
    .map(i -> new ItemWithTransaction(i, openTransaction()))
    .map(i -> i.conn.executeSql(..., i.item.prop1))
    . ...
    .map(i -> { 
        if (...) i.rollback = true; // error related to this item
        return i;
    })
    . ...
    .subscribe(i -> {
            ...
            if (i.rollback) i.conn.rollback();
            else i.conn.commit();
            i.conn.close();
        },
        e -> rollbackAndCloseAllOpenConnections(),
        () -> {...})
```

Generally I would not go with second approach, as it might require too many (uncontrolled) concurrent database connections.

3) You'd better restructure your code so that you collect all required information first, then do database update in one go in short transaction. This is how I would do it:

```
stream
    . ... // processing
    .buffer(...) // collect updates all or in batches
    .subscribe(Collection<ItemUpdate> batch -> {
            database.beginTransaction();
            try {
                ... // update multiple items
                database.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } finally {
                database.endTransaction();
            }
        },
        e -> {...},
        () -> {...});
```

Comment: I agree. First approach is better, but in your implementation database connection is opened in `doOnSubscribe`, so it affects all stream operations, upstream included. For example, if stream started from `Retrofit` observable it cause transaction to be opened much longer than it should be, that's why i have used `doOnNext` for it.

Comment: @Beloo If there are more than one item in stream it is going to affect upstream anyway. I've added real solution as number 3 to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a transformer to achieve **one** transaction for all items of stream:

```
 /** @return transformer which starts SQLite database transaction for each downstream operators,
 * closes transaction in {@link Observable#doOnTerminate}. So transaction will be closed either on successful completion or error of stream.
* set previously opened SQLite database transaction to completed in {@link Observable#doOnCompleted} call */
public <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> inTransaction() {
    return observable -> observable
            .doOnNext(o -> {
                if (!database.inTransaction()) database.beginTransaction();
            })
            .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                if (database.inTransaction()) database.setTransactionSuccessful();
            })
            .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                if (database.inTransaction()) database.endTransaction();
            });
```

And calling it:

```
stream
    //start transaction here
    .compose(inTransaction())
    .doOnNext(i -> /*database ops*/)
    .subscribe()
```

Note that i start transaction in `.doOnNext` and check each time if transaction was started already, because seems that it is impossible to call it only at first time.

Comment: Does this work fine for you? I use `ActiveAndroid`. @Beloo

Comment: yes, seems that it is working as expected. with green dao database, thought